# Aurelia: Error loading app-bundle script

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to move the index.html to a subfolder (in this case a folder called "app") but I am unable to make it to work with CLI. Here is my *aurelia.json*

```
{
  "name": "lv-app",
  "type": "project:application",
  "bundler": {
    "id": "cli",
    "displayName": "Aurelia-CLI"
  },
  "build": {
    "targets": [
      {
        "id": "web",
        "displayName": "Web",
        "output": "app/scripts"
      }
    ],
    "options": {
      "minify": "stage & prod",
      "sourcemaps": "dev & stage"
    },
    "bundles": [
      {
        "name": "app-bundle.js",
        "source": [
          "[**/*.js]",
          "**/*.{css,html}"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "vendor-bundle.js",
        "prepend": [
          "node_modules/requirejs/require.js"
        ],
        "dependencies": [
            // dependencies omitted
        ]
      }
    ],
    "loader": {
      "type": "require",
      "configTarget": "vendor-bundle.js",
      "includeBundleMetadataInConfig": "auto",
      "plugins": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "extensions": [
            ".html",
            ".css"
          ],
          "stub": true
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "platform": {
    "id": "web",
    "displayName": "Web",
    "baseDir": "./app"
  },
  "transpiler": {
    "id": "babel",
    "displayName": "Babel",
    "fileExtension": ".js",
    "options": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-es2015-modules-amd"
      ]
    },
    "source": "src/**/*.js"
  },
  "markupProcessor": {
    "id": "none",
    "displayName": "None",
    "fileExtension": ".html",
    "source": "src/**/*.html"
  },
  "cssProcessor": {
    "id": "postcss",
    "displayName": "PostCSS",
    "fileExtension": ".css",
    "source": "src/**/*.css"
  },
  "paths": {
    "root": "src",
    "resources": "resources",
    "elements": "resources/elements",
    "attributes": "resources/attributes",
    "valueConverters": "resources/value-converters",
    "bindingBehaviors": "resources/binding-behaviors"
  }
}
```

Al first I was having this error:

> ERROR [Bundle] Error: Unable to update vendor-bundle path to
>   app/scripts/vendor-bundle.js, could not find existing reference to
>   replace

**EDIT**

But I had configured the `baseDir` incorrectly.

After changing `"baseDir": "app/"` for `"baseDir": ". /app"` I'm getting a different error. When I load the web in localhost the app-bundle.js doesn't load apparently because it's pointing to the wrong route as can be seen in the next picture

[image]

As you can see in the next picture the vendor-bundle.js is loading from `localhost:9000/scripts` no `localhost:9000/app/scripts/`

[image]

Comment: I have a client who has done this. I'll ping them to see if they can help answer.

Comment: Oh, thanks! much appreciated

Comment: We have a way to resolve this. It will take a bit of writing up but I'll try and get something to you today.